# ngbDatepicker set current month and year dropdown

Tags: html, angular, ngb-datepicker

In my Angular application, I used a datepicker called ngbDatePicker. It seems that it has a bug because the default selected month and year dropdowns is not correct. See screenshot below:

[image: ngbDatePicker]

As you can see, the selected month is January and the year is 2011 but today is May of 2021. But if I check the value it is correct it's just that the dropdowns are not correct. For further reference, here is my code on using the ngbDatePicker:

```
<input class="form-control calendar pl-0 rounded" id="workDateSelector" (click)="d.toggle()" (dateSelect)="formatDate()" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [formControl]="selectedDate">
```

EDIT: Here is the code for the component:

```
selectedDate: FormControl;
date: Date = new Date();

ngOnInit(){
  this.selectedDate = new FormControl({year: this.date.getFullYear(), month:this.date.getMonth()+1, day:this.date.getDate()});
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `selectedDate`? Please provide some more code

Comment: I already edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Try [angular material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).The datepicker allows users to enter a date either through text input, or by choosing a date from the calendar